# variable in jquery function is null

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am having a problem with seeing one of my variables on a webpage. Here is what I have so far.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#CheckID").click(function() {
         // submit ajax job and display the result
         var id = '$("#ID").val()'      
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test_wID.php",
                data: "id",
                success: function(data) {
                $('#rightselection').html(data)
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This is the jquery function I am using to take an ID entered into a form and use that ID with a bash script.

Here is the php.

```
<?php

//Get the ID from the HTML form and use it with the check chunk script.

$id = $_POST['ID'];
if (is_null($id)){
        echo "$id is null";
}
echo "Selected test Game ID: ".$id;
//print shell_exec('/opt/bin/tester $id');

?>
```

I commented out the script because the variable is returning null, at this point I am just trying to make sure that I get the ID.

For completeness here is the form I'm using.

```
print "<p><h3>ID: <input type=\"text\" id=\"ID\" /></h3></p>";

#print "<br>";

print "<p><button id=\"CheckID\">Check ID</button></p>";
```

When i click the button I get the message in my div that the variable is null. So my question is am I missing something in the declaration? How is it that the `var id` is null?

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: And learn to sanitize input you are passing to shell commands ([`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg)) - even though it's currently commented out.

Answer (score 2):

You mixed up strings and variable references at two points.

First, the statement `var id = '$("#ID").val()'` assigns just a string to your `if` variable and not the return value of the jQuery call. So just remove the `'` here.

Second, the `data` parameter you're giving to the  `ajax()` call again consists just of a string `"id"` and not the respective value. Here you need to change to `{'id': id}`.

So after correcting everything, your code should look like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#CheckID").click(function() {
         // submit ajax job and display the result
         var id = $("#ID").val();     
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test_wID.php",
                data: {'id': id},
                success: function(data) {
                  $('#rightselection').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
});
```

<sup>Sidenote: Try to put all `;`, where they belong. This prevents some errors, which can be hard to track!</sup>

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comment by @FlorianMargaine you only need one wrapper not two around your code.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Overlooked that one. Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider changing your jQuery code to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test_wID.php",
    data: {id: $("#ID").val()},
    success: function(data) {
        $('#rightselection').html(data)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the two following snippets are **equivalent**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
});

// Is equivalent to:

$(function() {
});
```

So your code does the same as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    });
});
```

Plain useless, right?

Secondly, this line is plain wrong:

```
var id = '$("#ID").val()';
```

You're passing a **string** to the `id` variable. `$('#ID').val()` is **not evaluated**. This is the equivalent of doing this in PHP:

```
$id = '$_POST["id"]';
```

Which is just wrong, right?

You want this:

```
var id = $('#ID').val();
```

By the way, this variable naming could be improved, the same goes for the HTML ID.

Thirdly, you're doing the same mistake in the `data` option of `$.ajax`:

```
data: 'id'
```

You're just passing a **string** to the `data` option. **You want the value of the `id` variable.**

Then, if you absolutely want a string, I don't recommend it. jQuery expects a special kind of string. You better pass an object. Like this:

```
data: {
    id: id
}
```

Do you see why the variable naming is wrong? You can't differentiate the property from the value. If you had done the following:

```
var idValue = $('#ID').val();
```

You could use this:

```
data: {
    id: idValue
}
```

Which is way more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In your $.ajax call you need to do:

```
data : { id: id }
```

Comment: So you're just passing a string of a javascript statement?

Comment: no... id will be the name and then passing the value - you do not need quotes - it's just a JSON string you're defining here.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pass parameters in an AJAX call you need to pass a string similar to the GET string you see in urls. So something like: `d=123&name=test`

Change the line

```
var id = '$("#ID").val()'
```

To

```
var id = 'id=' + $("#ID").val();
```

Comment: NO! `var data = {id: $('#ID').val()}` - `id` is a bad variable name for the payload.